# Add target to links as file.js is being read

Tags: php, javascript

If I have a recent comments.js file (coming from another server) is there anyway I can add a TARGET="_top" to the links that are in the file.js as the file.js is being read and added to the page?

Reason: it is in an iFrame and unless I can add the target top... when you click on a link it will open the new page inside the iFrame. I need it to of course go to the top of the site.

I can't change the code or add the link targets myself on the original file.js coming from the other server.

It would have to be done as it is being downloaded.

The site is of course PHP

Thanks

Comment: Is the iframe page located on the same domain as your site? Or is it also being loaded from the other server?

Comment: Can you post an example or a URL to source ? As i am very confused what your actually trying to do !

Comment: @mads-jensen Yes... same domain

Comment: @manseuk it is for DISQUS comments, they have a recent comment widget and I want it to reload every minute or so but I can't get it done with regular javascript on the same page so I stuck it in a iFrame but that messes up the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript, you can manipulate the DOM of the iframe after loading is finished and add the target attributes:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function add_targets(iframe) {
                var links = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
                    links[i].target = "_TOP";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="links.html" onload="add_targets(this)"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside the iframe:

```
var linkArray = window.frames['frameName'].getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<linkArray.length; i++) {
  linkArray[i].target = '_top';
}
```

Or inside the iframe:

```
var linkArray = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<linkArray.length; i++) {
  linkArray[i].target = '_top';
}
```

You need to wrap either into an event that fires after all links from the external file has loaded.

Comment: I'll test this also, this also might be what I need, I know something will work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
window.frames[x].document.getElementsByTagName('a').each(function(item){
    item.setAttribute('target','_top');
})
```

Comment: I think this is what I need, I'll test it now.

Comment: Maybe that is why it didn't work... the jQuery? I see that now...hmmm.... have to test more and add jQuery file also?

Comment: you can do it using an array to iterate :)
`
var anchorsList=window.frames[x].document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<anchorsList.length;i++){
    anchorsList[i].setAttribute('target','_top');
}
`

Comment: forgot to mention, x being the index of the iframe..that can be a problem if you have more than one iframes if not use window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName('a')

Comment: @Mads Jensen does this look like jquery to you? http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml If you only know javascript by learning jqery, fine with me but get you head out of the bucket, setAttribute is plain old javascript...ofcourse, it is used in jquery and prototype and just about any othe js framework because nobody found the need to create a method that natively existed in javascript :) all the best!